# react hooks props in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-hooks

I have started using `react-hooks` and there is something I am trying to understand.
I have this `useEffect` hook, I'm separating my `useEffect` hooks, I want to know when each hook runs.

```
function MyComp(props) {
    useEffect(
       () => {
         fetchSomeData(props.filters)
       },[props.filters]
     )
    return (
        <div>will show my data here</div>
     )
}
```

Will this hook only run when `props.filters` has changed?

Or do I have to use the `prevProps` to check if it has changed?

Like this:

```
function MyComp(props) {
   const prevProps = useRef(props);
   useEffect(
       () => {
           if (prevProps.filters !== props.filters) {            
              fetchSomeData(props.filters)
           }
       },[props.filters]
   )
   return (
     <div>will show my data here</div>
   )
}
```

Comment: there is an error in the second `MyComp`. When you are using the `useRef`, the value is accessible via `current` object: e.g. `prevProps.current`. [Official document](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Answer (score 30):

If the value of `props.filters` did not change, then React would skip the effect.

```
// This will only re-run if the value of `props.filters` changes
useEffect(() => {
  fetchSomeData(props.filters);
}, [props.filters]);
```

With hooks, React does this internally unlike the implementation using `componentDidUpdate` where we have to compare the value of `prevProps` and `nextProps` against each other.

See [optimizing performance by skipping effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).